# How to obtain a bode plot for this circuit in Matlab online version

Tags: matlab, bode-plot, simulink

So I've an electrical circuit in matlab as follows:
[image]

I've already setup the points of linear analysis. But I can't the option for linear analysis in the linearization tab.

The problem is that I cannot find the options to show the bode etc. Previous (offline) versions of matlab gave no hassle.
Here's the menu:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a question more appropriate for the tool support folks.

Comment: Where's the input; where's the output. What's the floating pac-man shape bringing to the party?

Comment: The output is the right-most voltage sensor(with the x and upward arrow). The input is the left-most voltage sensor(with the x and downward arrow).